# projection - linear alebra

Tags: linear-algebra

$U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$; $v,w\in\mathbb{C}^n$;
$p$ is the projection of $v$ on $U$;
$q$ is the projection of $w$ on $U$.

I need to prove that:
$$\langle v,w\rangle  = \langle p,q\rangle +\langle v-p,w-q\rangle $$

I opened this way the right part:
\begin{align}
\langle p,q\rangle +\langle v,w-q\rangle-\langle p,w-q\rangle&=
\langle p,q\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle+\langle v,-q\rangle-\langle p,w\rangle-\langle p,-q\rangle\\
&=\langle v,w\rangle+\langle v,-q\rangle-\langle p,w\rangle
\end{align}

Hope I didn't have any mistakes till here but what can I do now?

Comment: you are not a newbie here, so (-1) for the awfull formating,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompose
$$
 v = p + (v-p), \qquad  w = q+ (w-q)
$$
and use the fact that $v-p$ and $w-q$ aro orthogonal to $U$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a projection is a projection onto a subspace $F$ parallel to another subspace $G$ where, if we denote $E$ the space, $E=F\oplus G$.

Now if you have a scalar product on $E$, and $\dim E < +\infty$, you can chose and $F$ and take $G=F^\perp$ which seems to be what you do. So we have an *orthogonal* projection.

---

In your case, $E=\mathbb{C}^n$, $F=U$, $G=U^\perp$

You have

$v=p+(v-p)$ where $p\in U, v-p \in U^\perp$

$w=q+(w-q)$ where $q\in U, w-q \in U^\perp$

Note that $\forall x\in U, \forall y\in U^\perp, <x,y>=0$

In particular, $<v-p,q>=0=<p,q-w>$

$<p,q>+<v-p,w-q> = <p,q>+<v-p,w>-<v-p,q>=<p,q>+<v-p,w>=<p,q>-<p,w>+<v,w>=<p,q-w>+<v,w>=<v,w>$